# How to call a Dart method from Kotlin using the pigeon library in Flutter

Tags: flutter, kotlin, pigeon

I'm working on a Flutter app that uses the `pigeon` library to interface with the native Spotify SDK. I have defined a `SpotifyAPICallback` interface in the `pigeon` file, which contains the `onAuthCode` and `onAuthFailure` methods that should be implemented on the Dart side.

Here's the relevant code:

Pigeon Declaration File (`pigeons/spotify_api.dart`):

```dart
import 'package:pigeon/pigeon.dart';

class SpotifyAuthCodeParams {
  late String clientId;
  late String redirectUri;
  late String scope;
}

@ConfigurePigeon(
  // ... pigeon configuration
)

@FlutterApi()
abstract class SpotifyAPICallback {
  void onAuthCode(String spotifyAuthCode);
  void onAuthFailure(String error);
}

@HostApi()
abstract class SpotifyAPI {
  void openSpotifyConsentView(SpotifyAuthCodeParams params);
}
```

Kotlin Implementation (`SpotifyAPIImpl.kt`):

```kotlin
class SpotifyAPIImpl(val engine: FlutterEngine) : SpotifyAPI {
    private var apiCallback: SpotifyAPICallback? = null
    // ...

    override fun openSpotifyConsentView(params: SpotifyAuthCodeParams) {
        // ... open Spotify consent view
    }

    private fun authFlow(resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        // ...
        when (response.type) {
            AuthorizationResponse.Type.CODE -> {
                println("Going back to flutter...")
                apiCallback!!.onAuthCode(response.code) // This is not being called on the Dart side
            }
            else -> apiCallback!!.onAuthFailure(response.error) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Dart Implementation (`SpotifyAPICallbackImpl.dart`):

```dart
class SpotifyAPICallbackImpl implements SpotifyAPICallback {
  @override
  void onAuthCode(String spotifyAuthCode) {
    print("Auth code from flutter: $spotifyAuthCode");
  }

  @override
  void onAuthFailure(String error) {
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

On the Kotlin side, I'm able to receive the Spotify auth code successfully. However, when I try to call the `onAuthCode` method from the Kotlin side, it's not being called on the Dart side.

I've tried adding a `setCallbackInstance` method to the `SpotifyAPI` interface to pass the `SpotifyAPICallbackImpl` instance, but `pigeon` doesn't allow using `@FlutterApi` classes in the `@HostApi` interface.

Can someone please guide me on how to properly set up the communication between the Dart and Kotlin layers using the `pigeon` library, so that I can call the `onAuthCode` method from the Kotlin side and have it executed on the Dart side?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.